# improving the performance of sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

```
var sorted = results.sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = "";
    var nameB = "";
    var str1 = a.date.toLowerCase() + " " + a.time;
    var str2 = b.date.toLowerCase() + " " + b.time;

    if (a.date.toLowerCase() != "" && a.time!= "") 
     nameA = Date.parse(new Date(str1))

    if (b.date.toLowerCase() != "" && b.time!= "") 
     nameB = Date.parse(new Date(str2))

    return nameA === nameB ? 0 : nameA < nameB ? -1 : 1;

});
```

1. Can anyone improve the code, if there any faults in the way i am
   sorting. Is there any better approach?
2. How can i implement `http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy` for the above
   sorting.

Comment: How can anyone improve anything when you do not say what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you are looking for a general code review, use http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: All I can say is: don't use the ternary operator like this. And comment your code (at least explain what you're doing somehow). Or don't expect people to put any efforts into reading it.

Comment: @bažmegakapa The ternary operator is fine there and that is common practice with sort functions. Do you really struggle to read them like if statements? It could use a () to make the second half a little more readable.

Comment: @epascarello Combining ternaries is never a good practice and is never justified. It's not readable and I admit I struggle reading it. If it makes you feel like a cool hacker to combine them, no problem, but then don't post it where other people should read it.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: Nonsense, format it more like `return nameA === nameB ? 0\n: nameA < nameB ? -1\n: 1;` (sorry, best I can do in a comment) and you get a crystal clear inlined lookup table that anyone can understand at a glance. However, mashing a compound ternary into one line is nasty and somewhat hostile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One major bottleneck in your code is that you're recomputing nameA/nameB on every sort operation. Considering that each element in array may take part in several comparisons, that's a lot of unnecessary work. You should first build sorting index using same algorithm and then sort with it instead. You can also store sort key in same object you sort so you can just check if it is here and don't recompute it if it is.

Another two things in your code are absolutely unnecessary: `.toLowerCase` on comparison with empty string and generation of useless `Data` objects, when `Data.parse` already specified explicitly as working with strings.

I've made two versions of improved sort - one with helper function (prettier, more correct ideologically) and inline - may give some extra speed-up on some JS engines. They both run roughly 3000 times faster than your original: http://jsperf.com/custom-date-sort.

(Oh, and helper function happens to be suitable for your underscore sortBy question).

With helper:

```
function fill_datetime_ms(obj){
    if (obj.date == "" || obj.time == ""){
        return obj.dateTimeMs = ""
    } else {
        return obj.dateTimeMs = Date.parse(obj.date.toLowerCase() + " " + obj.time)
    }
}

var sorted = results.sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = a.dateTimeMs
    var nameB = b.dateTimeMs
    if (!nameA && nameA !== "" && !nameA !== 0){
    nameA = fill_datetime_ms(a)
    }
    if (!nameB && nameB !== "" && !nameB !== 0){
        nameB = fill_datetime_ms(b)
    }

    return nameA === nameB ? 0 : nameA < nameB ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Inline:

```
var sorted = results.sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = a.dateTimeMs
    var nameB = b.dateTimeMs
    if (!nameA && nameA !== "" && !nameA !== 0){
        if (a.date == "" || a.time == ""){
            nameA = a.dateTimeMs = ""
        } else {
            nameA = a.dateTimeMs = Date.parse(a.date.toLowerCase() + " " + a.time)
        }
    }
    if (!nameB && nameB !== "" && !nameB !== 0){
        if (b.date == "" || b.time == ""){
            nameB = b.dateTimeMs = ""
        } else {
            nameB = b.dateTimeMs = Date.parse(b.date.toLowerCase() + " " + b.time)
        }
    }

    return nameA === nameB ? 0 : nameA < nameB ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Umm, [`sortBy`](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L266) does do a Schwartzian Transform, that's half the point of having it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing would be to have your a and b objects already have this calculated from the start. Than you just loop without having to process it. Or follow what Oleg says about storing it.